# CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't collapse anything

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to hide and show the toolbar when I scroll down and up in a recycler view fragment, but the CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

First I tried to do it with just the coordinator layout and it worked, but it's not as fluid as the collapsing toolbar layout (when it works that is)

Is it because the recycler view is in a fragment? What is the problem exactly?

Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.github.mpivchev.app.activities.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                            android:paddingTop="18dp"
                            android:text="TestString" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />
```

Part of fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your toolbar doesn't have a defined collapseMode, so there's no instruction for how it should behave. Add app:collapseMode="pin" to your Toolbar xml.

Comment: @Milen re-reading your question - I was assuming you were saying the toolbar wasn't collapsing. Just want to make sure I'm looking at the right problem. Is that what you mean by doesn't do what it's supposed to do?